# How to find a particular URL inside a domain using PHP?

Tags: php, url, filepath

I want to find a specific URL inside a domain that it is not indexed on the Google search engine. This website isn't mine and I don't have any privileges at all.

I have tried using a [Sitemap generator](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com) in hope it displays it:

```
http://www.example.com?user=9191919
http://www.example.com?user=3636363
...
```

But it allows me to see only `500` URLs.

---

Is there a PHP way to search this URL without using brute force?

I also know that it is stored at the path `"example.com/pages" + numbers`, so maybe this can shorten the search.

Comment: I updated the question. If it is still wrong, consider leaving a feedback. It is kind of hard to read minds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't very many practical solutions for what it seems that you are talking about. Brute forcing is the simplest solution if you have the time.

I will assume that you are wanting to search the page for certain content here.

```
<?php 
set_exec_limit(0);
ob_start();

$url_prefix = "http://www.example.com?user=";
$search = "FINDME";
$start = 10;
$end = 1000000;

for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){
    $content = file_get_contents($url.$i);
    if(stripos($content,$search) !== FALSE){
        print $url.$i." \n";
        ob_flush();
        usleep(500); # take it easy
    }
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

This ought to get you started if it's not already the whole darn thing. Easy peasy.

---

**PS:** Don't turn usleep() down any further. If anything, set it up to 1000 just to be safe. It's better to take time, not risks.